# c++ constants how to make them work

Tags: c++, oop, constants

So far I have used DEFINE to declare my constants. and it works perfectly fine.

I am trying to use the c++ const keyword in my classes but it gives compile time error

Header

```
  class User{

  public:
     User::User();
  protected:
       const float DATA_Z;

   }
```

.CPP

```
 User::User(){

         DATA_Z = 0.0023f;

  }
```

this is the error it generates

Error   3   error C2758: 'User::DATA_Z ' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list

How can I assign a data to it, and how can I use them in my class.

Comment: The error already says what you have to do. Put it in the initializer list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do this instead:

```
User::User() : DATA_Z(0.0023f) 
{
    // body of constructor
}
```

Constant members need to be initialized in the initializer list, because they cannot be assigned directly.  The same is also true for members that are reference-type, because you cannot change the referent of a reference variable.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is pretty clear. Move assignment into initializer list:

```
User::User(): DATA_Z(0.0023f)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To simply replace manifest constants defined with `#define`, write global `const`s:

```
#define DATA_Z 0.0023f
```

becomes

```
const float DATA_Z = 0.0023f;
```

Putting the constants into the class means you can have a different value in each object, which is why the other answers tell you to initialize it in the constructor. That's a legitimate design decision, but it's **different** from defining the value as a macro.

Answer (score 1):

The following code helps you to pass any value to initialize the `DATA_Z`:

```
`
   class User{
         public:
            User::User(float data=0):DATA_Z(data){}; // here `data` is a local parameter to receive            the assigned value.
        protected:
           const float DATA_Z;
   }
`
```

Comment: Two problems, one, he doesn't want to pass in the value of the constant, just specify it in the header. Second, you are initializing DATA_Z (a float) from an int parameter.